# Anime where the MC is granted powers by another being. He's the first male to ever be able to wield this power

Tags: story-identification, anime

A couple of years ago, I was browsing the web for something to watch when I stumble across the first episode of this anime that looked kind of interesting.

It starts with the normal main character having a normal day, living a normal life, when BAM! a supernatural creature attacks. I can't remember all the details, but I do remember the female warrior troupe that comes along to try and beat back the creature. Things aren't exactly going well, and the guy is doing his best to help given the circumstances, but things take a turn in their favor when this fairy (and she definitely looked like a fairy) comes along and offers her powers to the boy to save the day. He says yes, defenders win the day, the guy turns out to be the first male to ever gain this power (I think; I mean, the girls seemed pretty hung up on the fact a guy was wielding this power) everyone goes home ready for what's next.

---

It's not "Luck & Logic" or "Blade Dance of the Elementalers" (Seireitsukai no Blade Dance).

Comment: This is a story-identification question about an anime featuring "a supernatural creature" and a "fairy" that offers "powers", which sounds fantastical to me. Hence, I have migrated it here.

Comment: Is it where the girl captures the ghosts or souls who are wandering here and there and while fighting one is unable to defeat so she gives her power to the boy ?
It's name is ..... (wait I'll tell you soon)

Comment: [Bleach](http://www.absoluteanime.com/bleach/)?

Comment: @Valorum Bleach didn't feature female-only warriors like that

Comment: The first half of that description reminds me of the start of [Claymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claymore_(manga)), but there's no fairy and the boy doesn't help or get any powers.

Comment: The title alone reminded me of *Infinite Stratos*, but that's a mecha/harem anime, don't think there are any fairies in it. I'll have a look later.